# How to add all message boxes into on final message box in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Can anyone help us please. We have managed to get VBA to look through our data and find tickets that have been open for longer than 90days. But at the moment we can only make it so that each ticket appears as a sepparate message box. Is it possible to combine all the results at the end into one message box that has a list of the results and count the total number of results found? The code we are using is below.

```
Sub LongerThan3Months()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim startdate As Date
Dim datenow As Date
Dim Ticket As String
Dim days As Integer
Dim n As Integer

Sheets("Tickets").Select
With ActiveSheet
lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
End With

datenow = Date

n = 0

For i = 4 To lastrow
startdate = Range("B" & i).Value
days = DateDiff("d", startdate, Now)

If days >= 90 Then

   If Range("B" & i).offset(, 2).Value <> "Closed" Then
       n = n + 1
       Ticket = Range("B" & i).offset(, 3).Value
   End If
End If
Next i

MsgBox (n & " " & "Tickets have been open for over 90 days")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're going to want to concatenate the resutlts into one string.

Outside the loop you should get yourself a string variable.

```
  Dim msgStr as String
  Dim extraTickets as Long

  extraTickets = 0
```

Then add the concatenation of the `Ticket` field to the string each time.

```
   If Range("B" & i).offset(, 2).Value <> "Closed" Then
     n = n + 1
     Ticket = Range("B" & i).offset(, 3).Value
     If n < 30 Then
         'this will not happen on the 31st ticket.
         msgStr = msgStr & Ticket & vbcrlf
     End if
   End If
```

The `vbcrlf` is a `VB` constant for `Carriage Return, Line Feed` essentially the enter key. It will give each ticket its own line in the display.

```
 MsgBox (n & " " & "Tickets have been open for over 90 days" & vbcrlf & vbcrlf & msgStr)
```

Comment: Beat me to it. It's worth noting though that a `MsgBox` can only display a limited amount of information (not sure of the exact character/line count). Too many tickets and the later ones will be cropped off as I discovered when using a similar method to display update information for an Access Database. Still gets my +1.

Comment: @Aiken That's a good point. OP may want put a logic check to stop concatenating after n results.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers it works perfectly. What do you propose i do if reults do eventually end up being longer than a message box can take? Thanks again for you help

Comment: @MichaelAsaad You can put in a condition on the concatenate if you figure out a reasonable amount of tickets to be in the list. I will edit answer.

Comment: @Bmo I think 10 will be a good amount. But does limit the results to the first ten results it finds?

Comment: No, you'll have all the results in the data set. Your output will just stop after the number.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still not quiet sure what you mean, please bare with me. so if i have 11 results will i only see ten in the message box? Or will i be able to see the 11th if i scroll or something ?

Comment: Only 10 will be in the list but you won't be able to scroll. We're getting into an extended comment line here which is discouraged, I would play around with the answer, to some research on the `msgbox` and post another question if you have one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    Dim msgall As String
    msgall = ""
    ...
    For i = 4 To lastrow
      ...
      If Range("B" & i).Offset(, 2).Value <> "Closed" Then
          N = N + 1
          Ticket = Range("B" & i).Offset(, 3).Value
          msgall = msgall & <the message you want goes here> & vbCrLf
      End If
      ...
    Next i
    ...
    MsgBox msgall
```

The MsgBox may be too large, depending on your case.